# Как выводить категории постов в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

На главной странице планируем выводить категории постов(Виллы, Замки, Виноградники и.д.)
https://prestige.andreykurus.ru/index.html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в WordPress выводить категории постов с превьюшками на страницу??

То-есть как запускать стандартный цикл в php (have_posts() или get_posts) на вывод именно постов, я знаю, а вот с выводом категорий постов, что-то я не могу понять..

Comment: Используйте [get_terms()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую